# Under Onclick event trying to change activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am working on Custom ListView for an assignment given to me. I have worked out a custom list view by using Base Adapter. 
I have a Button in the view by clicking on which I want new activity to be started. But I am getting error on run time. Please note that BUTTON is not the part of the listview, I mean its not repeating, Its placed only once at the top of the layout with Listview included.

```
public class mainActivity2 extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.item_list);

    ArrayList<ItemInfo> items = GetSearchResults();
    final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylistview);
   if(lv1==null){

        Log.d("error","ListView is null");
    }

    lv1.setAdapter(new itemBaseAdapter(this, items));
    final Button btnShowCart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.shCart);
    btnShowCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
              Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Cart.class);
               startActivity(myIntent);         

        }
    });   


}

private ArrayList<ItemInfo> GetSearchResults() {

    ArrayList<ItemInfo> items=new ArrayList<ItemInfo>();
    items.add(new ItemInfo("pizza",R.drawable.icon,15));
    items.add(new ItemInfo("chicken",R.drawable.icon,10));
    items.add(new ItemInfo("slice",R.drawable.icon,12));
    items.add(new ItemInfo("hoha",R.drawable.icon,20));

    return items;
}
```

}

StartActivity(myIntent) is the line I am getting error at run time. 
Here is the code to it, I will be grateful if somebody shed light on the problem.

Comment: Try this Intent myIntent = new Intent(mainActivity2.this, Cart.class);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you add `Cart.class` to [manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832619/add-a-new-activity-to-the-androidmanifest) file? What is error log?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than new Intent(v.getContext, Cart.class), try:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, Cart.class);
```

Comment: See also dmytrodanylyk's suggestion about checking AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 1):

1) Maybe the problem lays in the v.getContext() method. Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mainActivity2.this, Cart.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

2) Maybe you did not register 'Cart' activity in the Manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace `v.getContext()` with `mainActivity2.this`.

Answer (score 0):

First, check whether your second activity has been added to your `Manifest.xml` file. And, after try with this code --

```
Intent i = new Intent(mainActivity2.this, Cart.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Maybe, it will helpful to you.