# Unfortunately, *name of app* has stopped

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, android-emulator

I have just started programming, and I am making an android version of the swedish law book. I have no errors in the code, but when I try to run it in the emulator, it starts up, but as soon as a press a button it says "Unfortunately, *name of app* has stopped."

I have looked through many other threads like this, but they have all been code specific and therefore of no use to me.

I am using Eclipse.

So, I was wondering if any kind soul could just look through what I have done a help me find a mistake?

This is the "Activity_Main_activity.xml" coding:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".HuvudMeny" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Kapitel 1, Om Brott och Brottspåföljder"
    android:onClick = "kapett" />
```

As you can see, its very simple.

Here is the MainActivity.java coding:

```
    import com.example.brottsbalken.Kap1;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;

    public class HuvudMeny extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_huvud_meny);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_huvud_meny, menu);
    return true;
}



    public void kapett(View view) {
Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, Kap1.class);
startActivity(intent1);
```

EDIT: Added LogCat. Did not know you needed this, sorry!

LogCat:

```
    03-27 16:33:46.371: E/Trace(795): error opening trace file: No such file or  directory (2)
    03-27 16:33:46.371: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:33:46.371: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:33:46.371: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:33:46.491: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:33:46.491: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:33:47.311: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:33:47.311: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:33:47.341: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:33:47.411: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:33:47.541: D/libEGL(795): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
    03-27 16:33:47.611: D/(795): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established          0x2a14b468, tid 795
    03-27 16:33:47.623: D/libEGL(795): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
    03-27 16:33:47.680: D/libEGL(795): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
    03-27 16:33:47.861: W/EGL_emulation(795): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    03-27 16:33:47.901: D/OpenGLRenderer(795): Enabling debug mode 0
    03-27 16:33:47.901: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:33:47.910: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:33:47.921: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:33:48.021: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:33:48.021: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:33:48.071: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:33:48.091: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:33:48.091: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:33:48.101: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:33:48.110: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:33:48.331: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:33:48.331: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:33:48.351: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:33:48.370: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:33:48.712: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:33:48.973: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:33:49.110: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:36:24.451: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:36:24.451: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:36:24.505: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:36:24.781: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:36:24.781: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:36:24.821: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:36:24.821: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:36:24.831: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:36:25.215: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:36:25.215: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:36:26.907: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:36:26.910: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:36:26.921: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:36:26.940: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:36:26.940: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:36:26.951: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:36:26.951: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:36:26.960: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:36:26.960: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:36:26.990: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:36:27.090: D/dalvikvm(795): GC_CONCURRENT freed 73K, 7% free 2718K/2908K,                          paused 5ms+4ms, total 164ms
    03-27 16:36:27.191: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:36:27.191: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:36:27.201: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:36:27.221: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-27 16:36:27.260: D/AndroidRuntime(795): Shutting down VM
    03-27 16:36:27.260: W/dalvikvm(795): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught  exception (group=0x40a70930)
    03-27 16:36:27.321: E/AndroidRuntime(795): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    03-27 16:36:27.321: E/AndroidRuntime(795): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
    03-27 16:36:27.321: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at  android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3597)
    03-27 16:36:27.321: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
    03-27 16:36:27.321: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
    03-27 16:36:27.321: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    03-27 16:36:27.321: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    03-27 16:36:27.321: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    03-27 16:36:27.321: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
    03-27 16:36:27.321: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    03-27 16:36:27.321: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    03-27 16:36:27.321: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    03-27 16:36:27.321: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    03-27 16:36:27.321: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    03-27 16:36:27.321: E/AndroidRuntime(795): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    03-27 16:36:27.321: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    03-27 16:36:27.321: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    03-27 16:36:27.321: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3592)
    03-27 16:36:27.321: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  ... 11 more
    03-27 16:36:27.321: E/AndroidRuntime(795): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {nackagymnasium.brottsbalken2/com.example.brottsbalken.Kap1}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
    03-27 16:36:27.321: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1618)
    03-27 16:36:27.321: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
    03-27 16:36:27.321: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
    03-27 16:36:27.321: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
    03-27 16:36:27.321: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
    03-27 16:36:27.321: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at   android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
    03-27 16:36:27.321: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at                       nackagymnasium.brottsbalken2.HuvudMeny.kapett(HuvudMeny.java:30)
    03-27 16:36:27.321: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  ... 14 more
    03-27 16:41:28.431: I/Process(795): Sending signal. PID: 795 SIG: 9
```

Here is the manifest, it looks pretty correct to me...

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="nackagymnasium.brottsbalken2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="nackagymnasium.brottsbalken2.HuvudMeny"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="nackagymnasium.brottsbalken2.Kap1"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_kap1" >
    </activity>
```

I changed the name of "Main Activity" to "Huvud Meny".

I figuered it must be something wrong with the Intent (genius), but I have no idea what it is.

If someone took their time and helped me I would be very happy!

Comment: Post your logcat, this will show where the error is

Answer (score 0):

> Have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml ?

Well, did you ?

See [Add a new activity to the AndroidManifest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832619/add-a-new-activity-to-the-androidmanifest)

Comment: I did not, I thought eclipse did that by itself. I will do that and check if that helps

Comment: Everything in the manifest looks fine to me, I added it aswell.