# Manually registering a new activity in manifest.xml

Tags: java, android, debugging, netbeans

tl;dr Look at title + netbeans

I've been writing a game as I have been learning both Java and Android*. Most of it has gone without a hitch- but here we go.
To my understanding- each screen (main menu, gameplay, highscores, ect) is a separate Activity and therefore needs a different layout.

Problem 1:
**EDIT: Solved. Thanks Daniel.**

Problem 2: Then in the GameActivity.java file there is an error of cannot find symbol (symbol main_1 location class layout). Help?

```
    package lolfighter.notriot;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import lolfighter.notriot.nojoke.R.*;
    // @author DEVELOPMENT 
    public class GameActivity extends Activity {
        @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(layout.main_1);
    }
```

Also why is the bundle icicle? I have not specified this anywhere.

**Edit- Not solved**

*- I am in a partnership of sorts with a friend- the original plan was that he would handle all the code and I would handle all the graphic resources (He took an actual class for the Java language) But he has ran into a roadblock. I can't ask him because he has limited internet access (lunch breaks only) and lives in a different state (we go to college together)

Comment: Please, consider improving the question.

Comment: explain for me please

Comment: @Daniel Following that one the second </activity> shows up red.

Comment: Check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832619/add-a-new-activity-to-the-androidmanifest

Comment: That helped. thanks daniel./*notsarcasm*/

Comment: @user2390828: red means syntax error, consider checking if all attributes are well closed, and other common errors...

Comment: It is really difficult to understand the question being asked here. Your code is not indented well and at first glance your post looks like a huge disorganized pile of text/code. You should state your question as simply as possible.

Comment: And if a certain portion of the post has been solved you should make it more obvious or remove it from the post completely to make it easier for others to understand you question.

Comment: @AlexLockwood sorry so used to Using a -er- gui coder where it does it itself. This is my 9th day into looking at Java Lemme take another shot (the first problem is solved)

Comment: Also, in the future you don't need to include the `import` or `package` statements... StackOverflow will assume those are correct. Also, remove the `.*` at the end of the statement: `import lolfighter.notriot.nojoke.R.*;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Problem 2: then in the GameActivity.java file there is an error of cannot find symbol (symbol main_1 location class layout). Help?

Change `layout.main_1` to `R.layout.main_1`.

> Also why is the bundle icicle? I have not specified this anywhere.

You can rename the variable to be whatever you want, it doesn't matter.

Comment: did you change the import statement to `import lolfighter.notriot.nojoke.R;`?

Comment: just now- it has reverted back to not finding symbol: varible main_1

Comment: Are there errors in your XML code? Is the `gen` folder being autogenerated by eclipse?

Comment: No. 
But I think I have figured it out. 
I go to the R.java and add the variable right?