# Android Eclipse no error..project stopped working

Tags: android

I am a newbie to android ...
my project is a notification project using parse.com...
there is no error but my project stopped working ...

the logcat is

```
09-27 17:44:48.422: E/AndroidRuntime(947): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-27 17:44:48.422: E/AndroidRuntime(947): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.parse.mech.ParseApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.parse.mech.ParseApplication" on path: /data/app/com.parse.mech-2.apk
09-27 17:44:48.422: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:504)
09-27 17:44:48.422: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4364)
09-27 17:44:48.422: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-27 17:44:48.422: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1294)
09-27 17:44:48.422: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-27 17:44:48.422: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-27 17:44:48.422: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
09-27 17:44:48.422: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-27 17:44:48.422: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-27 17:44:48.422: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-27 17:44:48.422: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-27 17:44:48.422: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-27 17:44:48.422: E/AndroidRuntime(947): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.parse.mech.ParseApplication" on path: /data/app/com.parse.mech-2.apk
09-27 17:44:48.422: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
09-27 17:44:48.422: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
09-27 17:44:48.422: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
09-27 17:44:48.422: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at       android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:968)
  09-27 17:44:48.422: E/AndroidRuntime(947):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:499)
 09-27 17:44:48.422: E/AndroidRuntime(947):     ... 11 more
```

this is my manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.parse.mech"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="4"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<application
    android:name="Mech"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".ParseStarterProjectActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

wat are the changes i have to do in this .....thanks in advance

Comment: First thing to understand.  There is an error or you would not have a crash.  Eclipse can only show you *compiler errors*, it cannot show you *runtime errors*.

Answer (score 0):

`com.parse.mech.ParseApplication`

Add this class to your manifest.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.parse.mech.ParseApplication" on path:    /data/app/com.parse.mech-2.apk
09-27 17:44:48.422: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
```

Add this to your manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ParseApplication"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832619/add-a-new-activity-to-the-androidmanifest

Comment: I've edited my answer.  This is really basic stuff.  You should follow the tutorials at developer.android.com

Answer (score 0):

I get this error when I run and load the application directly to my phone from Eclipse and in my phone the application is already running. So, if it's same for you then it's not a problem. If you want to avoid the error , you can try manually uninstalling the app from your phone/emulator and then try again running the project from Eclipse. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

: Didn't find class "com.parse.mech.ParseApplication" on path: /data/app/com.parse.mech-2.apk in your android manifest activity block if you precede your android name with a period the package path will be appended so if you have ".com.parse.mech2" it will look for "com.parse.com.parse.mech2 " so either remove the period or don't give full name. Also like Simon says you can have compile time errors,link time errors, runtime errors etc.logcat helps and learning to run the debugger also helps.

Comment: I have uploaded the manifest file ...wat are the changes should be made...please tell me

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to add `.` before your Class name of application

like     `name=.Mech`

or you can add full path

```
name = com.parse.mech.Mech
```

and thi too

```
com.parse.mech.ParseStarterProjectActivity
```

Your Manifest should be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.parse.mech"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="4"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<application
    android:name="com.parse.mech.Mech"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.parse.mech.ParseStarterProjectActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: i did everything....I ran the parse existing project downloaded from parse.com still i get the error