# gridview fullscreen activity error

Tags: android, android-gridview

I am getting error in fullscreen image. When I click on any image from gridview it shows unfortunately stopped.

```
public class FullImageActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView ivfullimage;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.full_image);

        ivfullimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivfullimage);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
        ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(FullImageActivity.this);

        ivfullimage.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);
    }
}
```

my error is

[image]

Comment: use `int position = i.getIntExtra("id",0);` instead `int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");`

Comment: still i get the same error....

Comment: Try to make `mThumbIds` static in `ImageAdapter`

Comment: still the same problem, any other idea?

Comment: you must post your logcat that we see why error happens.

Comment: Please post error log

Comment: you need add `FullImageActivity` in manifest file in application tag as activity

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832619/add-a-new-activity-to-the-androidmanifest for more info about adding your activity to manifest file

Comment: thanx.. my problem is solve....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you haven't add `FullImageActivity`in `manifest` thats why getting [ActivityNotFoundException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ActivityNotFoundException.html)

add this into ur manifest under application tag

```
 <activity
     android:name="FullImageActivity" >
 </activity>
```