# How do you add the sample code from the Android IBeacon Library to a simple 'Hello World app'

Tags: android, ibeacon, android-ibeacon

I want to use run the sample code from the Android iBeacon Library but I am unsure how to add it. I have created some simple apps at this stage. Could someone please guide me to add the sample code for managing an iBeacon.

Terry

Comment: Please tell what you've tried, whether you've found any documentation that you understand if there was any.

Answer (score 1):

First go through the [Quick Start Guide](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/configure.html) for the Android iBeacon Library, choosing the right section based on whether you are using Eclipse or Android Studio.  These steps cover how to download the library, link it with your existing project, and configure your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Once you do that, you can insert some of the sample code found [here.](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/samples.html)  The ranging sample code is the easiest to see in action.  You can copy the full source code of an `Activity` that does ranging by looking at the class [here.](https://github.com/RadiusNetworks/android-ibeacon-reference/blob/master/src/com/radiusnetworks/ibeaconreference/RangingActivity.java)  If you copy that file into your project, remember to add an `Activity` definition to your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Alternately, you can add ranging functionality to an exiting activity by copying all the methods in that example (and merge the contents of `onCreate`) and then making your `Activity` implement `IBeaconConsumer`.

Comment: I am not sure how to 'add an Activity definition to my AndroidManifest.xml'. Could you please show me how.

Comment: Knowing how to create new activities is one of several basic concepts that you must know to build an Android app.  I would read a tutorial (online or in print) to get the fundamentals down first.  That said, an answer to a similar question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832619/add-a-new-activity-to-the-androidmanifest

Comment: Hi, @davidgyoung None of the links for sample code work!

Comment: Hi, @santobei, please create a new question with specific info about the sample you are trying, exactly how you are using it, and what happens that is different than what you expect.