# Changing from listview to listview

Tags: android

I want my categories listview to change to my vechicles listview when i click on the vechicles item in the categories list. I am new to android development any help would be appreciated

```
public class CategoryFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener {

public CategoryFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor

}


View mView; // used to get access to findViewById function
private ListView CategoriesList; //Contains List Layout
private String[] CategoriesString; //Contains String Array

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, container, false);


    CategoriesList = (ListView) mView.findViewById(R.id.CategoriesListView);

    CategoriesString = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.CategoriesData);

    ArrayAdapter<String> objAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,CategoriesString);

    CategoriesList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    CategoriesList.setAdapter(objAdapter);

    return mView;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(arg2 == 1)
    {
        //Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(getActivity(),Categories_vehicles.class);
        startActivity(intent1);
    }
}

}
```

This is my list containing vehicles

```
public class Categories_vehicles extends Fragment {

View mView; // used to get access to findViewById function
private ListView VehiclesList; //Contains List Layout
private String[] VehiclesString; //Contains String Array

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.categories_vehicles, container, false);


    VehiclesList = (ListView) mView.findViewById(R.id.Vehicles_List);

    VehiclesString = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.VehiclesData);

    ArrayAdapter<String> objAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,VehiclesString);
    VehiclesList.setAdapter(objAdapter);


    return mView;
}



}
```

This is the updated logcat

`06-14 12:00:45.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2145): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-14 12:00:45.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2145): Process: com.genie_alpha, PID: 2145
06-14 12:00:45.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2145): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.genie_alpha/com.genie_alpha.Categories_vehicles}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.genie_alpha.Categories_vehicles cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
06-14 12:00:45.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
06-14 12:00:45.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
06-14 12:00:45.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-14 12:00:45.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
06-14 12:00:45.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-14 12:00:45.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-14 12:00:45.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-14 12:00:45.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-14 12:00:45.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-14 12:00:45.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-14 12:00:45.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-14 12:00:45.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-14 12:00:45.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2145): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.genie_alpha.Categories_vehicles cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
06-14 12:00:45.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
06-14 12:00:45.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
06-14 12:00:45.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2145):     ... 11 more`

Comment: when i use this code the emulator crashes

Comment: Can you include exception (logcat) information? May help for finding the problem cause.

Comment: Tell us which line the app crashes at.

Comment: I included the logcat information

Comment: add com.genie_alpha.Categories_vehicles to android manifest, but ALSO the naming convention in Java and specifically on Android would be 'CategoryVehiclesActivity'.

Comment: i added it to the manifest but now i get another error so i updated the logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logcat has the answer

`06-14 11:28:24.753: E/AndroidRuntime(2015): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to                       find explicit activity class {com.genie_alpha/com.genie_alpha.Categories_vehicles}; have you   declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

You need to declare the missing activity in your AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: can you explain how do i add this properly as i said above i am new at android programming

Comment: as i got most of my code my doing tutorials on youtube and such lol

Comment: this will help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832619/add-a-new-activity-to-the-androidmanifest

Comment: also, if it helps, please mark this as the right answer by clicking the check mark next to the answer

Comment: I added it and got a new error will post the new logcat now