# Linking actionbar buttons with Activity in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, settings

how can I link my setting buttons in the action bar with a another activity.

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.about:
            about(); // shows a dialogbox
            break;
        case R.id.settings:
            // I want to link this with my setting screen
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

I linked up my about action bar button with a dialog box but for my settings, I want it to go to another activity. How can I do this? The activity I want to link to is called settings.java

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.about:
            about(); // shows a dialogbox
            break;
        case R.id.settings:
            startActivity(this, settings.class);
            // This doesn't work?
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: I tried that, the app loads but when I press the setting button it force closes.

Comment: btw, correct me if I am wrong but don't we suppose to use .class instead of .java?

Comment: You're right, that was a typo. Can you post the crash logs?

Comment: I think i figured out what the problem is. I didn't add the activity to manifest. (I am not sure how to add it)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832619/add-a-new-activity-to-the-androidmanifest